# Prove $G = \{g : F \to F \; | \; g(x) = ax + b, a \neq 0\}$ (where F is an arbitrary fixed field) is a group under composition of functions

Tags: group-theory

I was wondering if G is a group under composition of functions and how to prove that. Any help would be highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of all fields? Or field automorphisms?

Comment: @MorganRodgers F is for all fields

Comment: @amWhy nope, first time posting this question.

Comment: Now with that comments I don't know if my answer is correct or you're asking other thing.

Comment: @MonsieurGalois thank you so much for your answer (which is very close to what im looking for). I'm fairly new to this so sorry in advance for any confusion. I will edit my question one more time hoping it will clear things up.

Comment: But is what you were looking for?

Comment: @MonsieurGalois I've edited the question, thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok. If you liked the answer you can put it as the correct.

Comment: @MorganRodgers I've edited the question, thanks for your adjustments.

Comment: As said by @MonsieurGalois, if the answer given is satisfactory to you, you should click the button to accept that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is a group because

- The automorphism identity is in $G$ (the automorphism with $a=1_F$, $b=0_F$)
- Is closed under operations:
  $$g\circ h\colon F\longrightarrow F$$
  $$gh(x)=g(a_hx+b_h)=a_g(a_hx+b_h)+b_g=(a_ga_h)x\ +\ (a_ga_h+b_g)$$
  (this can be understood as the automorphism $t(x)=(a_ga_h)x\ +\ (a_ga_h+b_g)$)
- It has inverses for any automorphism: if $g(x)=ax+b$, its inverse is $g^{-1}(x)=a^{-1}x+(-a^{-1}b)$ 
  $$
  g^{-1}\circ g(x)=a^{-1}(ax+b)-a^{-1}b= x+a^{-1}b-a^{-1}b=x
  $$
  $$
  g\circ g^{-1}(x)=a(a^{-1}x-a^{-1}b)+b= x-b+b=x
  $$
- It's associative (the operation is very easy to check)